# blur() working on jsfiddle but not on my local machine

Tags: jquery

When I run the same code from jsfiddle on my local machine it does not work. I do have jQuery linked because my other jQuery functions are working.

http://jsfiddle.net/g2kBm/56/

```
<div class="errorbox-good">
        <div>
            <div class="form-entry">
                <label>
                    <div> First Name
                        <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
                    </div>
                </label>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" required> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 

<div class="errorbox-good">
        <div>
            <div class="form-entry">
                <label>
                    <div> Last Name
                        <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
                    </div>
                </label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" required> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
$('input').blur(function() {
if ($('#fname').attr('value') == $('#lname').attr('value')) {
alert('Same Value'); return false;
} else { return true; }
});
```

Why isn't the alert being displayed for me?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you pulled in JQuery on your local copy? Did you check the error console?

Comment: Use either ready or load

Answer (score 3):

jsfiddle by default uses the [`jQuery.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method, which waits until all elements on a page are loaded. But based on the code snippet, you may be firing the Javascript before jQuery is loaded so nothing happens.

The solution is to enclose all your jQuery code inside a [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) or [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').blur(function() {
        if ($('#fname').attr('value') == $('#lname').attr('value')) {
            alert('Same Value');
            return false;
        } else { return true; }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside a `$(document).ready()` handler.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('input').blur(function () {
        if ($('#fname').attr('value') == $('#lname').attr('value')) {
            alert('Same Value');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```